# Ajax and json_encode echoing text instead of json in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, firefox

I have a small script that returns shipping costs into an HTML , from PHP/CodeIgniter.

Here's the PHP code, with some example data for the Array:

```
public function atualiza_frete_ajax() {

   $response_array = array(
       'html_select_frete' => "<form><select><option></option></select></form>"
           );                
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode($response_array);
  }
```

And the JS/jQuery

```
      function atualizar_frete_ajax() {
            var $form = $("#form-cep");
                $(".loading").fadeIn();
                $.ajax({
                    type: $form.attr("method"),
                    url: $form.attr("action"),
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: $form.serialize()
                    }).done(function(data){
                        $(".frete-valor").html(data.html_select_frete)
                        $(".loading").hide()
                     });
                event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Now the issue is: it works great in Chrome, but in Firefox I just get this nasty text output.

Here the printscreen of how FF outputs it: http://prntscr.com/5cfcgc

I've made sure the file encoding is UTF8 and no BOM, and I'm using the correct header before I echo the response.

Any clues?

Comment: can you include a small screen capture?

Comment: Which version of FireFox and jQuery are you using?

Comment: Do you have an old FireFox version? Also note that `event.preventDefault();` is useless here.

Comment: Firefox 33.1, and jQuery 2.1.0

Comment: Okay @S.Pols, so I removed event.preventDefault(). It works on `$(document).ready(function()` when I call the function, but when I submit from a <form>, it does not.

My form is:

`<form role="form" data-async action="atualiza-frete-ajax" method="post">`

Comment: I saw your previous comment, @MonkeyZeus, and yes, console has an error in FF: `TypeError: event is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are not preventing the default behaviour. `event.preventDefault()` is right, but you need to use it correctly. If you want to do this AJAX request at the moment the form is submitting you should use something like this:

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#form-cep',function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
            $(".loading").fadeIn();
            $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr("method"),
                url: $form.attr("action"),
                dataType: "json",
                data: $form.serialize()
                }).done(function(data){
                    $(".frete-valor").html(data.html_select_frete)
                    $(".loading").hide()
                 });        
    });
```

Also with this approuch you won't get the FireFox error anymore.

**EDIT**

If you also need it as function you can use this:

```
function atualizar_frete_ajax() 
{
    var $form = $("#form-cep");
        $(".loading").fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            dataType: "json",
            data: $form.serialize()
            }).done(function(data){
                $(".frete-valor").html(data.html_select_frete)
                $(".loading").hide()
             });
}


$(document).on('submit', '#form-cep',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    atualizar_frete_ajax();   
});
```

Comment: Nice. I'll give it a try. One catch, though: I have to call this is as a function in different parts of the script =/

Comment: Updated my asnwer, you can use something like this if you need it as function to.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Just one more question: what is difference from:

`$(document).on("submit", "#form-cep",function(e) {` and
`$("#form-cep").submit(function(e){` ?

Comment: The difference is that `$(document).on("submit", "#form-cep",function(e) {` will always work, even if you replaced your form with an AJAX request. If you replace your form with an AJAX request the `$("#form-cep").submit(function(e){` listener won't work anymore.